# Pass data to EnumPropery items callback

Tags: python, operator

I'm struggling to pass a variable to an EnumProperty items callback, resulting in making this variable a global, which I prefer to avoid. I want to be able to access the "plant" from the "model_callback", but I can't reference it as self.plant. I am unclear on the scope I'm running in within the callback.

Simplied example follows. Note that in the real example, the plant variable changes whenever the filepath is updated.

```
class ImportPlant(bpy.types.Operator, ImportHelper):
    bl_idname = "import_object.plant"
    bl_label = "Import Plant"
    # ...

    plant = ["spring", "summer"]

    def model_id_callback(self, context):
        items = []
        # Results in: AttributeError: 'IMPORT_OBJECT_OT_plant' object has no attribute 'plant'
        for model in self.plant:
            items.append((model, model, ""))
        return items

    model_id: EnumProperty(items=model_id_callback, name="Model")

    # ...
```

How can I access the plant variable in the model_id_callback without just making it a global?

Comment: The `plant` is a class attribute not an instance attribute, meaning that each object of type `ImportPlant` references the same `plant`. Therefore replacing `self.plant` with `ImportPlant.plant` should be the solution. (Currently on mobile, hence posted as comment and not as polished answer).

Comment: @RobertGützkow ah, I was confused because accessing the properties did work with self.filepath for example. Tested using the class name instead of self and it indeed works. This is slightly better than global :-) and since the ImportHelper is modal, I suspect it is sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: To test this further, I made plant a property: plant = property(get_plant, set_plant) and initialized it in __init__(). I can still refer to self.plant in the other methods of the class (draw, invoke, execute), but EnumProperty callback still reports: AttributeError: 'IMPORT_OBJECT_OT_lbw' object has no attribute 'plant'. Somehow, it feels like the callback is running in a different context.

Comment: Using a constructor in operators is a bit tricky, because the lifetime is limited to it's execution. I would have to look at your whole test script to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plant` is a class attribute and not an instance attribute, meaning that each instance of the class `ImportPlant` references the same `plant`. Therefore your script should use `ImportPlant.plant` instead of `self.plant`.